# Solving: How to find an inverse function for this function?

Tags: functions, inverse

I got this example:

[image]

and I am trying to find an inverse function to this function.
Could I ask you, please, how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `Solve` or `Reduce` (after using proper _Mathematica_ syntax).

Comment: What do you want the inverse to be when x=0?

Comment: bill: I just updated the equation. They just ask me to find the inverse function to the equation above, I am confused by the logarithm.

Comment: Defining `y[x_] := 2 + Log[Sqrt[x] - 1]` you get the answer with `InverseFunction[y]`, e.g. `InverseFunction[y][2]` yields `4`. You don't have to care about the warning when you work with real numbers `x > 1`.

Comment: Was the question a *Mathematica* question or just a mathematics question? If the latter: rewrite equation as $ln(-1+\sqrt{x}) = y-2$, then take the exponential of both sides, etc. (If the function is intended to apply just to reals, as noted you must restrict `x`-domain and then correspondingly restrict the `y`-domain of the inverse function.) Whether that's what *Mathematica* does with `InverseFunction` is probably known only to the developers.

Comment: Basic tip: start by exchanging $x$ and $y$ (here, that would make $x = 2 + \ln (-1 + \sqrt{y})$), and then use whatever operation necessary to make it in the form of $y = [something]$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
y &= 2 + \ln\left(-1 + \sqrt{x}\right)\\
y-2 &= \ln\left(-1 + \sqrt{x}\right)\\
e^{y-2}&=-1 + \sqrt{x}\\
e^{y-2} + 1 &= \sqrt{x}\\
x &= \left(e^{y-2} + 1 \right)^2
\end{align}
$$